# How to align text one below the other in a toggle button in android?

Tags: android, button, vertical-alignment

i am trying to add text to a image set as a toggle button ,android:textOn="abc xyz" and want the text abc and xyz to appear on a different line within the button.
Otherwise the text is causing the square shaped image to stretch out into a rectangle
 iam adding text via xml usings string.xml not using text view

Comment: can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Only set the background with the image that you want using "src", and and text like other button.

Answer (score 0):

**string.xml**

```
<string name ="title">abc\nxyz</string>
```

**togglebutton**

```
 <ToggleButton
android:textOn="@string/title"/>
```

Comment: bro the text is appearing on a new line but the buttons are displaced downwards and the base of buttons is disappearing